# Why is my XML file not validating, but is well-formed?

Tags: html, xml, validation

I am extremely new to XML and I have been pulling my hair out for the last 3 days over this simple file. As far as I now, EVERY element and attribute I declared is correct and I followed the textbook and re-read and re-did the assignment twice, but kept getting this one error. What am I missing, and how would I go about correcting the error and finally submitting my homework (late)?

Here is the error I keep getting, despite doing EXACTLY as the book said:

```
[Xerces-J 2.9.1] Validating "mdpba1.xml" against "Internal DocType Declaration" ...
```

Ln 33 Col 47 - Attribute "name" must be declared for element type "bands".
1 Errors

Here is my code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!--
   New Perspectives on XML
   Tutorial 2
   Case Problem 2

   Filename:         mdpba.xml 
-->
<!DOCTYPE bands [

<!ENTITY celtic SYSTEM "celtic.jpg" NDATA JPG>
<!ENTITY badger SYSTEM "badger.jpg" NDATA JPG>

<!ELEMENT bands (band+)>
<!ELEMENT band (name, city, logo?, competition)>
<!ATTLIST band cid ID #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST name grade (1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | juvenile | novice) #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT city (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT logo EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST logo source ENTITY #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT competition (event, event)>
<!ELEMENT event (tune+)>
<!ATTLIST event type (MSR | Medley) #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT tune (#PCDATA)>
<!NOTATION JPG SYSTEM "image/jpg">

]>
<bands name="Midwest Developmental Pipe Band">
   <band cid="c0001">
      <name grade="juvenile">School of Celtic Bagpipes &amp; Drumming</name>
      <city>Delafield</city>
      <logo source="celtic" />
      <competition>
         <event type="MSR">
            <tune>Charlies Welcome</tune>
            <tune>Mrs MacPherson of Inveran</tune>
            <tune>Brown Haired Maiden</tune>
         </event>
         <event type="Medley">
            <tune>Rowd's Hornpipe</tune>
         </event>
      </competition>
   </band>
   <band cid="c0002">
      <name grade="juvenile">Badger Pipes and Drums</name>
      <city>Madison</city>
      <logo source="badger" />
      <competition>
         <event type="MSR">
            <tune>Lord Alexander Kennedy</tune>
            <tune>Bob of Fettercairn</tune>
            <tune>Brown Haired Maiden</tune>
         </event>
         <event type="Medley">
            <tune>Out of the Air</tune>
         </event>
      </competition>
   </band>
   <band cid="c0003">
      <name grade="novice">Pardeeville School of Piping and Drumming</name>
      <city>Pardeeville</city>
      <competition>
         <event type="MSR">
            <tune>Lord Alexander Kennedy</tune>
            <tune>Bob of Fettercairn</tune>
            <tune>The Little Cascade</tune>
         </event>
         <event type="Medley">
            <tune>The Radar Racketeer</tune>
         </event>
      </competition>
   </band>
   <band cid="c0004">
      <name grade="3">Zoar Scottish Pipe Band</name>
      <city>Zoar</city>
      <competition>
         <event type="MSR">
            <tune>Charlies Welcome</tune>
            <tune>Mrs MacPherson of Inveran</tune>
            <tune>Major Manson</tune>
         </event>
         <event type="Medley">
            <tune>Miss Lily</tune>
         </event>
      </competition>
   </band>
   <band cid="c0005">
      <name grade="juvenile">Stockholm Pipe Band</name>
      <city>Stockholm</city>
      <competition>
         <event type="MSR">
            <tune>Pretty Marion</tune>
            <tune>The Sheepwife</tune>
            <tune>Brown Haired Maiden</tune>
         </event>
         <event type="Medley">
            <tune>Farewell to Erin</tune>
          </event>
      </competition>
   </band>
</bands>​
```

I am so inexperienced that I am unsure  how to work around the issue(S) without messing something up, and any help would be GREATLY appreciated, thank you...

Comment: Validation and well-formedness are two separate concepts. A document can be well-formed but not valid. (An ill-formed document can never be valid however for obvious reasons.)

Comment: [XMLValidation.com](http://xmlvalidation.com) says _“Attribute `"name"` must be declared for element type `"bands"`.”_.

Comment: Looks like your schema doesn't expect the attribute `name="Midwest Developmental Pipe Band"` on the `<bands>` element...

Comment: But that is how it was in the book/data files. I only created the DTD/elements and attributes. Every time I try to add "name" to "bands" element, it asks for a type and I have no idea which type to use without affecting something else...

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [your deleted question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32580283/xml-validator-keeps-asking-me-to-declare-a-name-attribute-that-does-not-exist) from yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is because your DTD specification in the XML header doesn't specify `name` as a valid or expected attribute for the element `<bands>`

If you add the required DTD definition for this attribute to your XML, it will validate.

`<!ATTLIST bands name CDATA #REQUIRED>`

Here is your corrected XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!--
   New Perspectives on XML
   Tutorial 2
   Case Problem 2

   Filename:         mdpba.xml 
-->
<!DOCTYPE bands [

<!ENTITY celtic SYSTEM "celtic.jpg" NDATA JPG>
<!ENTITY badger SYSTEM "badger.jpg" NDATA JPG>

<!ELEMENT bands (band+)>
<!ATTLIST bands name CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT band (name, city, logo?, competition)>
<!ATTLIST band cid ID #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST name grade (1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | juvenile | novice) #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT city (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT logo EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST logo source ENTITY #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT competition (event, event)>
<!ELEMENT event (tune+)>
<!ATTLIST event type (MSR | Medley) #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT tune (#PCDATA)>
<!NOTATION JPG SYSTEM "image/jpg">

]>
<bands name="Midwest Developmental Pipe Band">
   <band cid="c0001">
      <name grade="juvenile">School of Celtic Bagpipes &amp; Drumming</name>
      <city>Delafield</city>
      <logo source="celtic" />
      <competition>
         <event type="MSR">
            <tune>Charlies Welcome</tune>
            <tune>Mrs MacPherson of Inveran</tune>
            <tune>Brown Haired Maiden</tune>
         </event>
         <event type="Medley">
            <tune>Rowd's Hornpipe</tune>
         </event>
      </competition>
   </band>
   <band cid="c0002">
      <name grade="juvenile">Badger Pipes and Drums</name>
      <city>Madison</city>
      <logo source="badger" />
      <competition>
         <event type="MSR">
            <tune>Lord Alexander Kennedy</tune>
            <tune>Bob of Fettercairn</tune>
            <tune>Brown Haired Maiden</tune>
         </event>
         <event type="Medley">
            <tune>Out of the Air</tune>
         </event>
      </competition>
   </band>
   <band cid="c0003">
      <name grade="novice">Pardeeville School of Piping and Drumming</name>
      <city>Pardeeville</city>
      <competition>
         <event type="MSR">
            <tune>Lord Alexander Kennedy</tune>
            <tune>Bob of Fettercairn</tune>
            <tune>The Little Cascade</tune>
         </event>
         <event type="Medley">
            <tune>The Radar Racketeer</tune>
         </event>
      </competition>
   </band>
   <band cid="c0004">
      <name grade="3">Zoar Scottish Pipe Band</name>
      <city>Zoar</city>
      <competition>
         <event type="MSR">
            <tune>Charlies Welcome</tune>
            <tune>Mrs MacPherson of Inveran</tune>
            <tune>Major Manson</tune>
         </event>
         <event type="Medley">
            <tune>Miss Lily</tune>
         </event>
      </competition>
   </band>
   <band cid="c0005">
      <name grade="juvenile">Stockholm Pipe Band</name>
      <city>Stockholm</city>
      <competition>
         <event type="MSR">
            <tune>Pretty Marion</tune>
            <tune>The Sheepwife</tune>
            <tune>Brown Haired Maiden</tune>
         </event>
         <event type="Medley">
            <tune>Farewell to Erin</tune>
          </event>
      </competition>
   </band>
</bands>
```